# system date and object field date difference

Tags: datetime

I have one object which has one date/time field.

When I query that field value using workbench,it display as [2014-01-07T19:04:00.000Z
].

But when I go and check from force.com UI, it display as [08/01/2014 03:04].

What is happening? My timezone is Singapore.

How can I solve this issue?

As it makes us problem in querying the data from the db, leads us to get incorrect values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using with convertTimezone couldn't fulfill my requirement, I just use

```
format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
```

to convert into local timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Date values are always stored in UTC-00:00, while the UI will show times adjusted for your time zone. The "Z" indicates that the time is in UTC-00:00 time zone, and that you will have to adjust to find the time as it relates to you.

Comment: hi how can i convert to the singapore time zone before making the query? could you able to provide some code sample?

Comment: See [Converting Time Zones in Date Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm) for details on how you can query fields into local time.

Comment: Hi, is this applicable to both Date field and Date/Time field?